# SvelteKit build is working fine locally but on vercel it blews up?

Tags: web-deployment, svelte, vercel, vite, sveltekit

I am trying out the SvelteKit framework and playing with it. I build a dummy page and don't have any issue with the dev command and the build command finding components and sections. However, when I try to deploy it on the Vercel, Vite seems to be having trouble finding components.

> [vite:load-fallback] Could not load
> /vercel/path0/src/sections/About.svelte (imported by
> src/routes/index.svelte): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/vercel/path0/src/sections/About.svelte'

This is the config file I set up module alias and Vercel adapter.

```
import vercel from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel';
import { resolve } from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        // adapter: adapter(),
        adapter: vercel(),
        vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    $src: resolve('./src'),
                    $components: resolve('./src/components'),
                    $sections: resolve('./src/sections')
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

By default, Vercel CLI detecting output directory to be public but I overrode it by vercel_build_output. I also tried with auto adapter resulted in same issue. I tried deployment using github repo directly and with vercel cli too encountered the same issue. I tried it without alias too giving relative import like ../components resulted in same issue their too.

Comment: Is the filename (in git) the same as the import? `SidebarItem.svelte` and not `SideBaritem.svelte` or something like that? (could be a case-sensitive filesystem issue)

Comment: Can we see the GitHub repository so we might be able to trace it back easier

Comment: Sure  @Catalactics Here you go https://github.com/Abdulmoiz-Ahmer/portfolio.

Comment: @BobFanger i have updated file name and imports but I highly doubt that could be the issue. Here is the repository github.com/Abdulmoiz-Ahmer/portfolio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're filenames is `Sidebar.svelte` with a lowercase b while when you try to import it, it's `SideBar.svelte` with capital B
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very odd after changing the files I pushed the code why it didn't updated in github.